# margin padding у элемента при абсолютном позиционировании

Tags: css, position

подскажите, пожалуйста. если задавать отступы и поля для элемента с абсолютным позиционированием в виде %, то от какого элемента будут отщитываться эти % ?

```
<div class="head" >

<div class="head-fogging" >
</div >

<!--zindex 2-->
<div class="head-content" >
</div >
</div >
```

дело в том, что `.head` имеет `position: relative`. а `.head-content` `position:absolute`. но если задать для `head-content`  `margin-top:40%`, то `.head-content` уедет почти в самый низ контейнера `.head`

Comment: А не лучше ли для позиционирования использовать top\bottom\left\right ? Я думаю это то что вам нужно.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> если задавать отступы и поля для элемента с абсолютным позиционированием в виде %, то от какого элемента будут отщитываться эти % ?

И вертикальный и горизонтальный `margin`, заданный в процентах, будет рассчитываться от **ШИРИНЫ** родительского элемента с относительным позиционированием. То есть, если Вы задали `margin-top: 40%`, то `margin-top` будет составлять 40% ширины родителя (будет очень большим)

Вот Вам пример: высота родителя = 100px, а ширина = 1000px. А у дочернего элемента `margin` = 10%. В итоге, все его `margin` = 100% (что равняется 10% от ширины родителя)

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/ymvdVY)

```css
.container {
    position: relative;

    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;

    background: #ccc;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    margin: 10%;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```